# Is every algebra generated by some elements $\mathbb{Z}_2$-graded?

Tags: abstract-algebra, superalgebra

Let $A$ be an unital associative algebra generated by some elements $a_1,...,a_n$. Is it always possible to come up with a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-grading for $A$?

For example does it work if I consider the $a_i$ to be parity odd (and extend it in the sense that $a_ia_j$ is even etc.) and the unit to be parity even?

Comment: You can always give it the trivial grading, putting everything in degree $0$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I think we were thinking along similar lines -- see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the algebra $A = \mathbb{R}[x] / (x^2-x)$.  In this algebra, $x^2=x$.  How would you assign a parity to $x$ in this case?

Comment: I guess I would assign even parity?

Comment: @R.A. So what happened to your $\mathbb{Z}_2$ grading?

Comment: Yes, my idea wouldn't work here. But your algebra is noting but the algebra generated by $x$ over the reals with relation $x^x=x$. So I could define 1 and $x$ as even and get a grading, couldn't I?

Comment: Yes, but then the entire algebra is in the $0$-degree component, so the grading is trivial.  Of course you can *always* define a trivial grading over any algebra by just making everything degree $0$, as Petro Tamaroff mentioned in the comments.  Presumably you are interested in a *nontrivial* grading.

Comment: Ok, and it is true that there might be more than one non-trivial grading?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "might be".  There are algebras that can be graded non-trivially in more than one way.  But *this* algebra can't be graded non-trivially *at all*.